# how to keep the order of columns in the output of getting the mean?

Tags: pandas

How I can keep the order of columns unchanged when using groupby and mean?

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'f':[[1,2,30],[4,2,7]],'o':[[1,4,5],[7,1,3]],'e':[[6,7,4],[4,5,7]]})
```

my code is:

```
df.stack().str[1].groupby(level=1).mean()
```

output is:

```
e    6
f    2
o    2.5
```

but I want the following output which is the same as order of my columns in df:

```
f    2
o    2.5
e    6
```

Comment: Add another column to your data to use as a group indices (give all f's a 1,all o's a 2, and so on). Then you have something to order your results by after aggregation.

Comment: I am looking for a simpler method, some method in pandas

Comment: None of those means are correct... what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: the order of columns in the output is not the same as the order of columns in df

Comment: Are you responding to me? If so, your comment doesn't make sense. The mean of 1, 2, and 30 is 11, not 2...

Comment: Furthermore, `df.stack().str[1]` gives the result you seek, but again, it's not a mean... It's not really clear what you're doing with the `str` indexing.

Comment: @ddejohn I think you didn't get the mean part, I updated the input to make it more clear.

Comment: `str[1]` means the second elements of each list. how did u get 30?

Comment: What do you mean, "how did u get 30"? Before you edited you had a single list for `f` which was `[1, 2, 30]` the mean of which is 11.

Comment: So... you want to average the second value of each list for each column? If that's the case your `o` mean is incorrect.

Comment: ok right, but I think my question is clear,

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you are using Python 3.6+ in which Dict objects are ordered while `df` is defined.

Then run

```
df.stack().str[1].mean(level=1)
```

Output:

```
f    2.0
o    2.5
e    6.0
```

Which seems to preserve order. However, there is a depreciation warning (since Pandas version 1.3.0):
`FutureWarning: Using the level keyword in DataFrame and Series aggregations is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use groupby instead. df.median(level=1) should use df.groupby(level=1).median().` which is the origin of OP's question - *the suggested command does not preserve order*.

A quick fix is to manually assign an order afterwards, e.g.

```
df.stack().str[1].groupby(level=1).mean()[['f','o','e']]
```

But best solution is to disable sorting in`groupby`:

```
df.stack().str[1].groupby(level=1, sort=False).mean()
```

Comment: Of course, you can store your desired order (e.g. from column order of `df`) in a variable and apply after the `mean()` call.

Comment: I knew about this method, but since my column names change I can't use it. I thought there might be a method to do that

Comment: @user15649753 Does `df.stack().str[1].groupby(level=1, sort=False).mean()` work for you? The change in column order was due to implicit sorting in `groupby`.